# Is it possible to level up a 1.15 villager using commands?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

Is it possible to level up villager using commands like this: `/data modify entity @e[type=villager,limit=1]  merge value {level:4}` (which doesn't work)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct syntax is:

```
/data modify entity @e[type=minecraft:villager,limit=1] VillagerData.level set value 4
```

Comment: Oh, I learned old version of commands (1.12), I am still learning thet new :). Going to try that now.

Comment: Hmm, is there a way to make the villiager add xp and new offers too?

Comment: You can use the same command to modify other NBT tags. Villager NBT structure: https://minecraft.gamepedia.com/Villager#Data_values